# How to use a signal from one function generator to gate another signal from another function generator?

Tags: signal, function-generator

I have 2 function generators with me and each is outputting its own signal. The first one is a 100kHz square signal and the second one is a 10MHz sine signal. What I want to do is use the first signal as a gate signal to gate the second signal.

What should happen is that when the square signal goes up, the sine signal is then produced as a burst for x-amount of periods and then the sine signal will stop when the square signal goes down.

How can I go about accomplishing this? Thank you!

PS: I am using the SIGLENT SDG5162

Comment: What type of function generators do you use? Do they support this feature?

Comment: I'm using the SIGLENT SDG5162

Comment: What happens if you set the 100kHz square to CMOS level and connect it to the gate input of the 10MHz sine signal generator?

Comment: I don't think I have that function to set it to that level :/ I'm not even getting an external signal from the first function generator right now

Comment: CMOS means your signal goes from low(0V) to high(5V), and what do you mean you don't even get an external signal from the first generator?

Comment: so I put my square signal as free running and connected its output port into my oscilloscope and its just giving me noise... which means its not even providing an output signal right now

Comment: Is the output enabled?

Comment: yes! enabled it and now the output works! I plugged in the output of the first signal into the ext trig/gate port of the second function generator. I left the first signal free running and turned on gated burst on the second one with the source set as external, but its giving me this: https://imgur.com/VeMn5c0

Comment: Your square signals seems to be set as +-50mV, try CMOS levels (0/5V)

Comment: yup! played around with it and i think it works! thank you :)

Comment: So I'll sum up my comments in an answer

Answer (score 1):

The function generator offers an external input for gating function. Use the 100kHz square wave signal in CMOS TTL level(0V-5V) to gate the second function generator generating the 10MHz sine signal.